# Angular CLI build fails because it tries to `mkdir /opt/build` but has no access rights > where does 'opt/build' come from? and how to change it?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, babel-loader

I use the `node 14.15.5` docker image to run `ng build` but it fails with the following error message:

```
./node_modules/google-protobuf/google-protobuf.js - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/opt/build'

./node_modules/ngx-monaco-editor/fesm2015/ngx-monaco-editor.js - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/opt/build'

./node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/opt/build'
```

I have no idea why it even tries to create the build directory in `/opt`.

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.17
Node: 14.15.5
Package Manager: npm 6.14.11
OS: linux x64

Angular: 12.2.16
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1202.17
@angular-devkit/build-angular      12.2.17
@angular-devkit/core               12.2.17
@angular-devkit/schematics         12.2.17
@angular/cdk                       12.2.13
@angular/cli                       12.2.17
@angular/material                  12.2.13
@angular/material-moment-adapter   12.2.12
@schematics/angular                12.2.17
rxjs                               6.6.7
typescript                         4.3.5
```

the `outputPath` in `angular.json` looks like this:

```
{
    ...
    "projects": {
        "dashboard3": {
            ...
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/dashboard3",
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What do I miss???

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to permission try

```
sudo ng build --configuration=production
```

Comment: resolving the issue with `sudo` is no option since the build should not write into `/opt/`.
I would like to know why it (what?) tries to write into `/opt/` and how I can change that.

Answer (score 0):

in mac, you have to use "sudo ionic serve -l"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).